# How to retrieve an address of an object allocated by new operator in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, memory, new-operator

I'm new to C++ and I'm confused with the way `new` operator works.

I set aside memory on the heap for an object, like this:

```
string *myString = new string ("This is a string").
```

If I want the address to this object, I use the address operator, like this:

```
&myString
```

and receive the hex address of the first character of myString:  `0x28f3328`

If I use the object name without the address operator:

```
myString
```

I get a different hex number in return (`0x7a5380`).

What is the second number?  Does it mean anything, or is it merely some random value?

Comment: show some well-formated part of code that describes the situation that you are trying to understand.

Comment: &myString would give you the stack address where(string**) and myString would give you the actual heap address which has been allocated.SO the 2nd number is actual heap allocated one.

Comment: This is how your question should have looked like when you posted it. You would be getting upvotes instead of downvotes :)

Comment: ... although it doesn't seem that you put enough of effort of finding the answer on your own, these are basics that are quite easy to find

Answer (score 1):

You've got an object pointer, `string *myString;`. When you take the address, such as `&myString`, you do not get the address to the object! You get the address to a pointer to it. Since `myString` is a pointer, it already *is* the address to your object.

As a way to make this more clear, consider the following:

```
string *myString = new string("...");
string *anotherPointer = myString;
```

In this code, both `myString` and `anotherPointer` point to the same object; there's exactly one object here. However if you look at `&myString` and `&anotherPointer` you'll see that these pointers are at different places.

Answer (score 1):

This is the distinction between the address of the pointer and the address of what's pointed to by the pointer.

```
std::string *myString = new std::string;

std::cout << &myString << std::endl; // prints the address of the myString pointer
std::cout << myString << std::endl; // prints the address of what myString points to
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*myString = new string ("This is a string").
```

Here `myString` itself is pointer, so it is keeping address of some memory, i.e. *its value is address*. If you `&myString`, you will get address of `myString`, because pointer also have some address in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean standard class `std::string`

The direct response on you question

> How to retrieve an address of an object allocated by new operator in
>   C++?

is that operator new returns the address of the object allocated in the heap.:)

In this statement

```
std::string *myString = new std::string ("This is a string");
```

you define object `myString` that has value that is the address of the unnamed object of type `std::string` allocated in the heap.

So using expression `*myString` you access the unnamed object directly. for example

```
std::cout << *myString << std::endl;
```

Expression `&myString` is the address of object myString itself. It is not the address of the unnamed object allocated in the heap.

Compare these two statements

```
std::cout << *myString << std::endl;

std::cout  << **&myString << std::endl;
```

They give the same result. However in the second statement you have to apply two times `operator *`

Answer (score 0):

Use objects with automatic storage duration always when it is possible:

```
std::string myString("Some string");
std::string* ptrToString = &myString;    // initializing pointer with an address
```

Note that it is extremely unlikely that you will need a pointer to `std::string` object, clean code would probably handle it using reference.

---

But in case you would really allocate it dynamically, then this line:

```
std::string* ptrToString = new std::string("Some string");
```

creates an object (most likely on the heap) and assigns its address to `ptrToString` making it point to this memory. But `ptrToString` itself is a variable with automatic storage duration, it is a memory where address of your string has been stored. `&ptrToString` yields an address of memory, where pointer is stored.